# retrive data from mysql node red

Tags: node-red

I want to get a simple output from NodeRed mysql node .

I inserted the data into db with a function :

```
data = (msg.payload);
var m = {
 topic : "INSERT INTO `data`.`mytable` (`two`) VALUES ('" + data + "');"     
};
return m;
```

then I made another select function after db to retrive data :

```
m = {
 topic : "SELECT `two` FROM `data`.`mytable`;"     
};
return m;
```

[image]

I get the msg :

```
SELECT `two` FROM `data`.`mytable`; : msg.payload : undefined
undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

The second function will not actually run a query unless you feed it into another mysql node.

The debug node is only set to show the `msg.payload` and since the message only has a topic that explains the output you have shown.